# How mapping round with some floating numbers and range() works in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, range

I have the following Code:

```
circle_areas = [3.56773, 5.57668, 4.00914, 56.24241, 9.01344, 32.00013]
result = list(map(round, circle_areas, range(2, 7)))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[3.57, 5.577, 4.0091, 56.24241, 9.01344]
```

But if I pass one value to `range()` like  `result = list(map(round, circle_areas, range(2)))` it outputs `[4.0, 5.6]`, `result = list(map(round, circle_areas, range(3)))` it outputs `[4.0, 5.6, 4.01]` and it goes on.

I want to know why and how it acts like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to know how `round`, `range` and `map` built-in funcions works:

`round` receive one parameter in a obligatory way and a second parameter in a optional way.

```
a1 = 3.14159
a2 = round(a1)
print (a2)
```

output:

```
3
```

The optional second parameter is used when rounding to a specific decimal point is required:

```
a3 = round(a1,1)
a4 = round(a1,2)
a5 = round(a1,3)
a6 = round(a1,4)
print (a3)
print (a4)
print (a5)
print (a6)
```

output:

```
3.1
3.14
4.142
3.1416
```

The `range` built-in function, in a simple way, is a representation of ordered numbers. it receive one parameter in a obligatory way and a second & third parameter in an optional way.

When we use one parameter it means it starts in 0 and finish in a number before the parameter we have given, for example:

```
b1 = range(10)
b2 = list(b1) # we convert it to a list to see its content
print (b2)
```

output:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

When we use two parameters it means it starts in the first parameter we given and finish in a number before the second parameter we have given, example:

```
b3 = range(2,7)
b4 = list(b3) # we convert it to a list to see its content
print (b4)
```

output:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

The third optional parameter means a constant increment (or constant decrement if we use a negative number), example:

```
b5 = range(2,7,2)
b6 = list(b5) # we convert it to a list to see its content
print (b6)
```

output:

```
[2,4,6]
```

Finally, `map` built-in function is a special function that receive two parameters in a obligatory way and a third or more parameters in an optional way.

The first parameter is a function that execute something (a sum, a rounding, a square root, etc ), the second parameter is an iterable object (list, tuple, range, etc.). What "map" does is apply to each element of the iterable what the function, entered as the first parameter, would do to a single element, example:

```
#define a function to get the square root:
def sqrt(x):
    return x**0.5
#define an iterable:
c1 = [3.56773, 5.57668, 4.00914, 56.24241, 9.01344, 32.00013]
#using `map` function
c2 = list(map(sqrt,c1))
print (c2)
```

output:

```
[1.888843561547647, 2.361499523607828, 2.002283696182936, 7.499493982929781, 3.0022391643571633, 5.656865739965904]
```

In `map` function, a third or more optional parameters (always iterables objects) is used ONLY when the function entered as the first parameter can accept the same quantity of aditionals parameters entered (between obligatory or optional parameters), example:

```
#define a function to get a sum of 2 variables:
def sum_of_two(x,y):
    return x+y
d1 = [3.56773, 5.57668, 4.00914, 56.24241, 9.01344, 32.00013]
d2 = range(2,7) # "range" object contains 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6
#using `map` function
d3 = list(map(sum_of_two,d1,d2))
print(d3)
```

output:

```
[5.56773, 8.57668, 8.00914, 61.24241, 15.01344]
```

This happens because the `map` function did a sum between elements for each iterable just as the `sum_of_two` function says:

sum_of_two(3.56773,2) = 3.56773 + 2 = 5.56773

sum_of_two(5.57668,3) = 5.57668  + 3 = 8.57668

sum_of_two(4.00914,4) = 4.00914  + 4 = 8.00914

sum_of_two(56.24241,5) = 56.24241 + 5 = 61.24241

sum_of_two(9.01344,6) = 9.01344 + 6 = 15.01344

And what about `d1[5]` = 32.00013 ?, in this case `map` function uses the iterable with the fewest elements, limited by `d2`.

Returning to your question:

```
#define my first iterable
circle_areas = [3.56773, 5.57668, 4.00914, 56.24241, 9.01344, 32.00013]
#define my second iterable
second = range(2,7) # "range" object contains 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6
result = list(map(round, circle_areas, second))
print(result)
```

output:

```
[3.57, 5.577, 4.0091, 56.24241, 9.01344]
```

So what is happening here is:

round(3.56773,2) = 3.57

round(5.57668,3) = 5.577

round(4.00914,4) = 4.0091

round(56.24241,5) = 56.24241

round(9.01344,6) = 9.01344

Again the last element of `circle_areas` object (32.00013) is obviated of the process, limited by `range(2,7)`.

Finally with your last example:

```
result = list(map(round, circle_areas, range(3)))
```

output:

```
[4.0, 5.6, 4.01]
```

what is happening here is:

round(3.56773,0) = 4.0

round(5.57668,1) = 5.6

round(4.00914,2) = 4.01

Limited by `range(3)`, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

`map` can map consecutive pairs (triads, etc.) elements from multiple iterables (in your case `circle_areas` and the `range` generator) to the function you're mapping (as long as the function you're mapping accepts that number of arguments - 2 in your case). When you do the operation:

```
result = list(map(round, circle_areas, range(2, 7)))
```

The result you get is the same as:

```
result = [round(ar, prec) for ar, prec in zip(circle_areas, range(2,7)]
```

Therefore when you restrict the range generator to `range(2)` (values 0->1) `result` will only include the first and second values of `circle_areas` rounded to 0 and 1 decimal places consecutively.